# Easiest way to get a total count and a count of a subset?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I was trying to do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*) FROM attend
            WHERE (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,start_date) = 2 OR DATEPART(WEEKDAY,start_date) = 6)
            AND empl_no = 12345
        )
        FROM attend as a
 WHERE empl_no = 12345
```

But this seems a little ugly.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is it the duplicate where clause parts or repeated use of same table that you find ugly?

Comment: FYI: A CTE provides no performance benefit - nate c's answer is the most efficient means.

Comment: You might like to look [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ea41d0277c08bcf9587b8cdc0a128044) - I **know** it's PostgreSQL, but the basic laws of physics hold for all of the RDBMSs! 3 table scans versus 1!!! There really is no contest as to the "correct" answer! @OMGPonies is right! Checked SQL Server [too](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=75568c4cdcb176964f82b82fa0acb158) - it's fairly clear - two/three table scans vs. 1!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx):

```
WITH T1 AS (
    SELECT DATEPART(WEEKDAY,start_date) AS weekday
    FROM attend
    WHERE empl_no = 12345
)
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T1) AS total,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T1 WHERE weekday = 2 OR weekday = 6) AS subset
```

Comment: Not hitting the attend table twice should help with performance especially if your query involved other tables.

Comment: @abe Miessler: If you're concerned about performance then the very first thing to ensure is that you have indexed your table correctly otherwise all the solutions will perform poorly. You probably need an index on `empl_no`.

Answer (score 15):

Use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total,
       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, t.start_date) IN (2,6) THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS weekday
  FROM ATTEND t
 WHERE t.empl_no = 12345
```

Comment: Could you use `IF` instead of `CASE` (no difference on outcome): `IF(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, t.start_date) IN (2,6), 1, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

[`CUBE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175939%28SQL.90%29.aspx) and [`ROLLUP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) are very useful for dealing with final and intermediate aggregates all in one shot.  For this type of question CUBE would be a good fit if the final and intermediate totals were needed so this and similar questions could be answered without additional queries from the source table. I've found CUBE very useful for avoiding round trips to the DB.  However, in the case where the exact requirements are known ahead of time a single focused select (nicely demonstrated by @nate c) makes the most sense.

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (total int, weekday int)

INSERT INTO @T1
SELECT COUNT(1), DATEPART(WEEKDAY,start_date)
FROM attend
WHERE empl_no = 12345
GROUP BY DATEPART(WEEKDAY,start_date) WITH CUBE

SELECT 
    (SELECT Total FROM @T1 WHERE weekday is NULL) AS total,
    (SELECT SUM(weekday) FROM @T1 WHERE weekday = 2 or weekday = 6) AS subset

-- continue using @T1 or a table variable was seriously overkill
```

Comment: Never do in two queries, what you can do in one.  Also, the CTE provides no performance improvement - the CTE contents are re-run for each subselect.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: good call.  I removed the mention of CTE and rephrased usefulness of CUBE for this.