# Count rows with a specific condition in aggregate query

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery, aggregate-functions

I have this query to get the number of `PlayerSession`s with `reconnect = TRUE`, grouped by `Player.country`:

```
SELECT
    country,
    COUNT(*) AS with_reconnect
FROM PlayerSession S LEFT JOIN Player P ON (P.id = S.player_id)
WHERE reconnect = TRUE
GROUP BY country
```

I'd like to modify it to show not just the reconnected session count, but also the total count, something like:

```
SELECT
    country,
    COUNT(*) AS total,
    (COUNT WHERE reconnect = TRUE) AS with_reconnect
FROM PlayerSession S LEFT JOIN Player P ON (P.id = S.player_id)
GROUP BY country
```

Is this possible, and if so, what is the proper syntax?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414539/easiest-way-to-get-a-total-count-and-a-count-of-a-subset for various approaches

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
SELECT  Country,
        COUNT(*) AS Total,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Reconnect = true THEN 1 END) AS With_Reconnect
FROM    PlayerSession S 
        LEFT JOIN Player P 
            ON P.id = S.player_id
GROUP BY country
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Searching for this from 3 hours :)

Answer (score 19):

The following will suffice

```
SELECT
    p.country,
    COUNT(*) AS total,
    SUM(IF(s.reconnect=TRUE,1,0)) AS with_reconnect
FROM PlayerSession s

INNER JOIN Player p
ON p.id = s.player_id

GROUP BY p.country
```

I just rewrote the query.  You'll always have a Player row for every PlayerSession, so changed it to be an INNER JOIN.  Also the CONCAT was not needed as there will always be PlayerSession rows in this query (unless there are no sessions)

Comment: Hmm, it appears the parentheses don't match up.

Comment: Sorry about that, bracket blindness, fixed :)

Comment: In one quick test, I found that the SUM(IF()) method shown here was faster than the COUNT(CASE) method shown in the accepted answer.

Comment: Another benefit over the accepted answer is this will return `0` instead of `NULL` when no rows match the condition

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    country,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN reconnect = TRUE THEN S.player_id ELSE NULL END) AS with_reconnect,
    COUNY(*)
FROM PlayerSession S LEFT JOIN Player P ON (P.id = S.player_id) 
GROUP BY country
```

Comment: `ELSE NULL` is redundant, if you do not specify an `ELSE` the result is `NULL`, however this is fairly trivial and I am a fan of using `COUNT` rather than `SUM(CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` when the desired outcome is a count and not a sum, so you got my vote! Also change COUNY to COUNT...

Comment: @GarethD - I know that is redundant, but it makes it more clear that way

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    country,
    COUNT(*) AS total,
    sum(case when reconnect = TRUE then 1 else 0 end)  AS with_reconnect
FROM PlayerSession S LEFT JOIN Player P ON (P.id = S.player_id)
GROUP BY country
```