# Using Count() in multiple SQL statements and joining them with join

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, count, union

I have the below 3 SQL queries that look like this:

1- `SELECT Player FROM ShotTarget Group By Player`

2- `SELECT COUNT( Target ) FROM ShotTarget Where Target = 'OnTarget' Group By Player`

3- `SELECT COUNT( TARGET ) FROM ShotTarget Group By Player`

How can I put these 3 queries all together? I have tried with union and union all but I cannot get this to work.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint, you need to select player details to `JOIN` from your second and third queries.

Comment: What output you are expecting. provide the sample table which is expected.

Comment: All 3 queries are strange. The first one uses the group by clause with no aggregate functions. The second one shows the count of "on target" shorts for each player, one row to a player, without indicating who the player is. The third counts all shots for each player, one row to a player, without indicating the player. None of these seem like they would be anything you want. Can you explain what you're trying to find and maybe give some example data?

Comment: Is this [tag:mysql] or [tag:sql-server]? It's currently tagged with both.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easiest way to get a total count and a count of a subset?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414539/easiest-way-to-get-a-total-count-and-a-count-of-a-subset)

Answer (score 3):

That is what the `select` clause is for.  You can have multiple columns there.

```
SELECT Player, COUNT( TARGET ),
       SUM(case when Target = 'OnTarget' then 1 else 0 end)
FROM ShotTarget
Group By Player;
```

The tricky one is the one with `Target = 'OnTarget'`.  This uses conditional aggregation (a `case` statement in an aggregation function).

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you're trying to get the stats for each player, which infers a `group by` clause. The distinction between on-target and other shots could be achieved by some `CASE` trickery:

```
SELECT   player, 
         COUNT (target) AS total_shots
         COUNT (CASE target WHEN 'OnTarget' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS shots_on_target
FROM     ShotTarget
GROUP BY player
```

NOTE: `COUNT` ignores `NULL` values - this is the basis for the `shots_on_target` calculation.

Comment: Note: The default value is `NULL` when a record doesn't meet any `WHEN` criteria, so `ELSE NULL` is redundant. Nothing wrong with including it, just a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.player, COUNT(st.target)
FROM player p
    JOIN ShotTarget st ON st.player = p.player
WHERE st.Target = 'OnTarget'
GROUP BY p.player
```