# Subsets count on Hive using CTE

Tags: hive, hiveql

I want to count the rows in a Hive table and at the same time, count the subsets (based on certain conditions in WHERE clause) in a single query. I came across CTE in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414539/easiest-way-to-get-a-total-count-and-a-count-of-a-subset), which I think applies to non-Hive SQL. I've researched a bit and found out that Hive has CTE. However this form does not work in Hive when I tried:

```
WITH MY_TABLE AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM orig_table
    WHERE base_condition
)
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MY_TABLE) AS total,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MY_TABLE WHERE cond_1) AS subset_1,
    ...
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MY_TABLE WHERE cond_n) AS subset_n;
```

Does anyone have a workaround or similar working idea for Hive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for Common table expressions.  Use case when clauses to sum over conditions:

```
select count(1) as total
    , sum(case when cond_1 then 1 else 0 end) as subset_1
    --...
    , sum(case when cond_n then 1 else 0 end) as subset_n
from orig_table
where base_cond
;
```